# customized log4j.properties vs default log4j.properties of Maven project with Jboss Studio

Tags: jboss, log4j

When I created a maven project using camel-archtype-blueprint (or -spring) by Jboss developer studio, jboss studio generated a default `log4j.properties`  under the `src/main/resources`. If I tried to learn how to customize my logging of the project  to a specific location and format, can I modify that default one? Will that affect the default loggings which appear in the jboss fuse environment/serviceMix (if the maven project is going to be a bundle under the fuse/serviceMix)?

Do I have to include the statement
`final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SerialCommX.class.getName());`

for each class in my project, provided changing the class variable in the getLogger()?
How can all logging information be written into the same `out.log` file defined in the `log4j.properties` file?

Comment: All logging information will be handled by the library, log4j, which will centralize your logging based on the given configuration, so on your second and third question: yes, include the logger field in the class where you want to use logging; logging information will be handled transparently by log4j. Concerning your first question, did you try it out? Did you get any unexpected behavior?

Comment: I tried my customized in my pure java project, not within a fuse/maven project.  So I have not find any affect in the fuse.   I played my customized log4j.properties a little, referring it within other classes and understood how it functions.  I will configure an one in my fuse -camel project to see the effect on logging.  Thanks.